# child route configuration with Angular 8

Tags: angular, routes, angular-load-children

I have an app with angular 8 in which a have created two module:

- testModule and SimulatorModule

the simulator is having a routing file but the testModule doesn't.

I want to load all the component in the Simulator as children of the TestComponent found in TestModule.

But when I run the app expecting test component to be lunch, I'm always redirect to appComponent.

these are the code:

```
**//app.routing.ts**
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
{
 path: '', 
 redirectTo: 'simulator',
 pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
 path: 'simulator',
 loadChildren: './simulator/simulator.module#SimulatorModule'
}
]
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })
 ],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 providers: []
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and

```
//simulator.routing.module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Route } from '@angular/router';

import { SimulatorPageComponent } from '@app/simulator/simulator-page/simulator-page.component';
import { Test } from '@app/test/test.service';


const routes: Routes = [
  Test.childRoutes([
    {
      path: '',
      component: SimulatorPageComponent
    }
  ])
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class SimulatorRoutingModule { }
```

and

```
  //Test.service
  static childRoutes(routes: Routes): Route {  
    return {
      path: '',
      component: TestComponent,
      children: routes,
      data: { reuse: true }
    };
  }
```

who has an idea please of what is not going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it like below. Ofc, you might do it any other way.

Folder strukcute:

- /default
- /foo

  - /sub
- /foo-bar

`src/app/app-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', // localhost:4200/
        loadChildren: () => import('./default/default.module').then(m => m.DefaultModule), // lazy load
    },
    {
        path: 'foo', // localhost:4200/foo
        loadChildren: () => import('./foo/foo.module').then(m => m.FooModule), // lazy load
    },
    {
        path: 'foo/bar', // localhost:4200/foo/bar
        loadChildren: () => import('./foo-bar/foo-bar.module').then(m => m.FooBarModule), // lazy load
    },
    {
        path: 'baz', // localhost:4200/baz
        component: BazComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

`app.component.html`

```html
<header><!-- code --></header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer><!-- code --></footer>
```

Because I use `loadChildren`, I need a component loading. So I need more "xy-routing.module.ts" in `./default`, `./foo` and `./foo-bar` directories:

For example `foo-routing.module.ts` what included into `foo.module.ts`.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', // every time is ''. Ofc, you can use ':id' here -> when /foo/100   
        component: FooComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FooRoutingModule {
}
```

---

If you want to use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `src/app/foo-bar/foo-bar.component.html`

`src/app/foo-bar/foo-bar-routing.module.ts`

```js
onst routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: FooBarComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'sub', // localhost:4200/foo/bar/sub
                loadChildren: () => import('./sub/sub.module').then(m => m.SubModule) // src/app/foo-bar/sub/sub.module.ts
            },
        ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FooBarRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: #Numichi thanks for your answer. this one is perfect because they are routing file for all the modules. but in my case TestModule is not having a routing file. but only one component (TestComponent) and simulator components are sub components of this TestComponent.

Comment: Then look `BazComponent`. "baz" has not routing file.

Comment: but "baz" is a component it's normale. Take for example the "foo" Module( second route of app.routing) and assume that the foo module is a sub module of foo-bar module but foo-bar module doesn't have a routing file. how will you proceed? Please look at my post again if you can understand my problem better!

Comment: Your idea should work. I tried it in my dev projekt and it work, if contept is "SimulatorPageComponent" content of TestComponent. I don't know exist is a `<router-outlet>` in test.component.html where load SimulatorPageComponent.

Comment: It work:
https://github.com/Numichi/stackoverflow-angular8/tree/child-route-configuration-with-angular-8/src/app

Comment: i had a look on your code. I saw that testComponent and simulatorPageComponent are in the same module. but for me testcomponent is in another module named TestModule and TestModule doesn't have a routing file.

Comment: I pushed a new commit: https://github.com/Numichi/stackoverflow-angular8/commit/13137c39988f881ff2f5f759931e926cdcda3674

Where there is children-routing, there must be a component declaration what has an <router-outlet>. Like in example: `TestComponent`. (Without it, Angular doesn't know where include child component in this module. So you will get error message. You can try it: remove from simulator module, and add shared import-export array.) 
 

After it, you can create "shared module" with declarations-imports-exports to every child like in example: `PageSharedModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much Numichi for your help. Finally it's working. The main issue is that it was showing just a blank page and i didn't know how to check those errors, so after opening the console and applying your suggestiong gradually it works.